# Need to Sum the Values and then Minus Credit and Debit Note in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Hi Please help me out i Need to Sum the Values and then Minus Credit and  Debit Note in Oracle   9i

```
ID   Acc_TYP     Amt  


1     CR         100
2     CR         200
3     DB         50
4     DB         50
```

Using the Above Table Structure, I Need to Compute the Balance by (CR-DB), how to form the logic
in Single Query, Please help me to solve the issue , am very beginner in oracle. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried writing a sql for this?  It's rather easy. Hint: use _case when_ construct.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(
         case 
            when acc_typ='CR' then amt
            when acc_typ='DB' then -amt
            else 0
         end) as balance
from the_table
where acc_typ in ('CR', 'DB');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use CASE statement:

```
select sum(case when Acc_TYP='DB' 
                then -amt 
                else amt 
           end ) from t
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another Case-based solution, using a "simple case statement": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm#i8305

```
select sum(case acc_type
             when 'CR' then +amt
             when 'DB' then -amt
           end) balance
from   ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
select sum(n) from (
(select sum(amt) as n from table where acc_typ='CR') 
union 
(select -sum(amt) as n from table where acc_typ='DB')
)
```

Comment: -1 for inefficiency, and the possibility of a wrong answer when the sum of credits equals the minus the sum debits due to the implicit distinct in UNION.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Care to elaborate? How would this solution return a wrong answer if the sum of credits and debits are equal (which AFAICT can only happen if both sums return 0, unless we allow negativ amounts)?

Comment: There's nothing to suggest (in the question or in accounting principles) that negative amounts are forbidden. Anyway, if sum(amt) for credits is "10" and sum(amt) for debits is "-10", then -sum(amt) for debits will be "10". Adding those ought to give "20", but the UNION will eliminate one of the "10"s and the answer will be "10" instead of the correct "20". http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/72810/11